# how to fill blank of column from one data frame to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, automation

i have a 2 dataframe, i wanted to fill the ID column blank with help first column ID.
The data is not Identical the second data  is having less number of entry. And  I have to find the id values with respect to the C_name column.  If C_Name  and I'd of 1st data is equal to the 2rd data value the  value from 1 data should come  to 2 data frame

```
C_Name  ID  item ID
Ad  ADV01   ADV001
NC  899 NC01
NC  899 NC01
Med 14996   0-A
Bank    20668   BNK002
Light   LIG01   LIG01
Light   LIG01   LIG03
Light   LIG01   LIG03
Light   LIG01   LIG03
Ad  ADV01   AD01
Ivar's  IVARS01 I01
Ad  ADV01   AD01
Light   LIG01   LIG03
OneNet  ONT01   ONENET001
Light   LIG01   LIG03
Tri CAL01   201-TP
Tri CAL01   201-SPK
Tri CAL01   201-CHI
Light   LIG01   2059
Light   LIG01   2059
Light   LIG01   2059
Light   LIG01   2059
Light   LIG01   2059
Distribution    DMSI01  2052
```

second data

```
C_Name  ID  item ID
Ad  ADV01   ADV001
NC  899 NC01
NC      NC01
Med 14996   0-A
Bank    20668   BNK002
Light   LIG01   LIG01
Light       LIG03
Light       LIG03
Light       LIG03
Ad  ADV01   AD01
Ivar's  IVARS01 I01
Ad  ADV01   AD01
Light   LIG01   LIG03
OneNet  ONT01   ONENET001
Light   LIG01   LIG03
Tri CAL01   201-TP
Tri     201-SPK
Tri     201-CHI
Light   LIG01   2059
Light       2059
Light       2059
Light       2059
Light       2059
Distribution    DMSI01  2052
```

how should i do it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: `first data` and `second data` look almost identical. Are they supposed to be? Also, it's hard to understand what you're asking. Are you looking to add a column to the second data frame or are you looking to clean up the second column based on the value in both data frames?

Comment: Actually the second data  is having less number of entry. And  I have to find the id values with respect to the C_name column.  If C_Name  and I'd of 1st data is equal to the 2rd data value the  value from 1 data should come  to 2 data frame.

Comment: hi there, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [series.update(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) as

```
df2.ID.upadte(df1.ID)
```

Careful with

1. Pandas aligns the indexes of both series, so if there is not a significant index defined it wil work with the default RangeIndex. If this is the case and dfs don't the same amount of rows in the same order then you will get unexpected results.
2. All non-NA values from df1 will be copied to df2, if df2 already had a value it will be overwritten